# How to display VM Hostname as hostname and not IP?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, vmware-vcenter, netbackup

I had a problem while adding some VM into NetBackup.
VM Hostname is shown as IP, but I need to display it as hostname. This problem appear while try to add linux machine, for Windows machines it works fine.

PS. On linux machine I configure 

/etc/hostname: `nserv01`

/etc/hosts: `127.0.0.1 localhost` `192.168.55.219   nserv01`

but when search for all VM -> VM Hostname is shown as 129.168.55.219. How to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to configure a [PTR record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) in your DNS for the IP->hostname reverse lookup.

Comment: Thar resolve problem. But it's possible without adding this machine in DNS? for example configure some files?